# Is it better to use the Bootstrap CDN or is it prefered to download and use the bootstrap css and javascript files?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How do i know when should i use what and which one is preferred?
I have tried using both and found that loading files through a CDN was giving me better loadtimes but i've seen articles online saying that downloading the files is a much better way.
I am just a beginner please help.

Comment: _“but i've seen articles online saying that downloading the files is a much better way”_ - and what _reasoning_ did those articles give for that?

Comment: Both have pros and cons. https://www.google.com/search?q=use+cdn+or+local

Comment: they said that downloading the files gives greater control and customization over what I would normally get via a CDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in developing the site, it wouldn't matter if you download it and use. When you are up for production, CDN is better.

It will speed up the site(not drastically). When a browser loads a web page it reads the HTML file first. then it checks URL or CSS, javascript and images. If it is offline/on your server then it will ask your server to get CSS, javascript, images and fonts for bootstrap.

If you test your website with google web tool or any other page speed analyzer, CDN showed a better result.